# T-SQL Select where Subselect or Default

Tags: sql-server

I have a SELECT that retrieves ROWS comparing a DATETIME field to the highest available value of another TABLE.
The Two Tables have the following structure

```
DeletedRecords
 - Id (Guid)
 - RecordId (Guid)
 - TableName (varchar)
 - DeletionDate (datetime)
```

And Another table which keep track of synchronizations using the following structure

```
SynchronizationLog
 - Id (Guid)
 - SynchronizationDate (datetime)
```

In order to get all the RECORDS that have been deleted since the last synchronization, I run the following SELECT:

```
SELECT 
   [Id],[RecordId],[TableName],[DeletionDate] 
FROM 
   [DeletedRecords]
WHERE 
   [TableName] = '[dbo].[Person]' 
   AND [DeletionDate] > 
   (SELECT TOP 1 [SynchronizationDate] 
    FROM [dbo].[SynchronizationLog] 
    ORDER BY [SynchronizationDate] DESC)
```

The problem occurs if I do not have synchronizations available yet, the T-SQL SELECT does not return any row while it should returns all the rows cause there are no synchronization records available.
Is there a T-SQL function like COALESCE that I can use with DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery should look like something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX([SynchronizationDate]), '0001-01-01')
FROM [dbo].[SynchronizationLog]
```

It says: Get the last date, but if there is no record (or all values are NULL), then use the '0001-01-01' date as start date.

**NOTE** '0001-01-01' is for `DATETIME2`, if you are using the old `DATETIME` data type, it should be '1753-01-01'.

Also please note (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.100).aspx)

> Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.

**EDIT**

An alternative solution is to use `NOT EXISTS` (you have to test it if its performance is better or not):

```
SELECT 
   [Id],[RecordId],[TableName],[DeletionDate] 
FROM 
   [DeletedRecords] DR
WHERE 
   [TableName] = '[dbo].[Person]' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM [dbo].[SynchronizationLog] SL
     WHERE DR.[DeletionDate] <= SL.[SynchronizationDate]
   )
```

Comment: This works perfectly
COALESCE((SELECT MAX([SynchronizationDate]) FROM [dbo].[SynchronizationLog] GROUP BY [SynchronizationDate]), '1753-01-01')